# Prove that the standard matrix of reflection of R^3 in a plane is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove that the standard matrix of reflection of R^3 in a plane is symmetric. I know that the matrix of an orthogonal projection of R^3 is symmetric, but why is it also the same for reflection? Would it be also orthogonal?

Comment: Notice that such a matrix can be diagonalized through an orthogonal matrix, containing a base of the plane and its perpendicular vector.

Comment: if we write a column vector $(x,y,z)^T,$  what 3 by 3 matrix takes that to $(x,y,-z)^T \; \; ? \; \; $

Comment: I am even more confused...

Answer (score 0):

A reflection is not a projection. For projections you always want $p^2 = p$, but for reflections, you expect $r^2=\text{id}$.

Now to your question. Suppose you have a plane given in $\mathbb{R}^3$, say with directions $v$ and $w$ which are orthogonal and of unit length. You can always extend these two to an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, say $\{v,w,z\}$ with $z$ also of unit length. Then you can write the matrix in this basis as

$$r = \begin{pmatrix}1 &0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

This matrix clearly is symmetric.

If by 'standard matrix' you mean the matrix for the standard basis, note that you can always find an orthogonal matrix (change of basis) $U$ such that the matrix $r$ in standard basis reads $U^T rU$. But then we get

$$(U^T r U)^T = U^T r^T (U^T)^T = U^T r U,$$

so this matrix will also be symmetric.

Comment: so it would be always orthogonal?

Comment: Yes. Being orthogonal for a matrix means that the dot products of vectors do not change if you apply the matrix. If you think about it, you will find that it makes sense that a reflection has this property.

Answer (score 0):

All reflections in dimension 2 ar
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & -\cos \theta
\end{array}
\right)
$$

With column vectors $u,v$ we have $ u \cdot v = u^T v = v^T u  .$

In contrast, $u v^T$  is a square matrix, so is $v u^T.$  When $u \neq v,$ these are transposes of each other.

When we have unit column vector $u,$ the reflection across $u$ has matrix
$$   I - 2 u u^T $$
with result
$$ f(v) = v -2 u u^T v = v -2 u (u\cdot v) = v - 2(v\cdot u) u  $$
This is called a Householder reflection.

Note how, if $v$ is perpendicular to $u,$ we find $f(v)=v$
If $v$ is parallel to $u,$   so that $v=tu$ for real $t,$
$$ f(tu) = tu - 2 (tu\cdot u) u  = tu - 2 t (u \cdot u)u = tu - 2tu = -tu $$

The matrix is $I - 2 u u^T.$  Its transpose is the same, so it is symmetric